# Can't see Listview with ArrayAdapter in Android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

I'm trying to make a simple app displaying a list with a ArrayAdapter, but nothing is displayed in the list (The debugger shows it is properly filled).

Can you help me to figure out what's wrong?

Adapter code:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Item> ffList = new ArrayList<>();


    public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> list) {
        super(context, 0, list);
        mContext = context;
        ffList = list;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View listMember = convertView;
        if (listMember == null)
            listMember = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_member, parent, false);

        Item currentFile = ffList.get(position);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) listMember.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        TextView txtTitle = listMember.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

        if (currentFile.isUpload()) {
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.upload);
        } else {
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.download);
        }
        txtTitle.setText(currentFile.toString());
        return listMember;

    }
}
```

Code in the onCreate() method to display the list

```
    mFileList =  findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayList<Item> listOfFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfFiles.add(new Item("Name","0k", true, "", false));
    listOfFiles.add(new Item("Name2","1k", false, "", false));
    mAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, listOfFiles);
    mFileList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the protection of the list. It was private, so the adapter couldn't detect and inflate it.
I hope this can help other absent-minded people as me.